# Constructors and Destructors of abstract base class as protected?

Tags: c++, constructor, abstract-class

I read somewhere that constructors of an abstract base class should be kept protected ? Why is this a recommended practice and how can these be misused if not kept protected ?

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to me. I think it depends on this "somewhere" where you have read this.

Comment: I, personally, feel it documents proper usage.

Comment: In c++ an abstract class needs to have a pure virtual method. This prevents them for being initialized. However, if you have a class that has no pure virtual method but you still want to prevent it from being used outside of inheritance the above method will do that. But i would not call it an `abstract base class`.

Comment: Maybe it would be useful if you could supply us with a reference to this "recommended practice"? In either case, it is not a very commonly occurring advice in C++ and doesn't actually achieve anything.

Comment: By not keeping them private but protected will help the derived classes to initialize the private members of ABC, is something that I can think of. But if kept public, can these be misused ?

Answer (score 1):

If you see this as recommended practice you should ask the person who actually recommends this. Abstract class in C++ is a class that have at least one pure virtual function. Compiler will not let you create instance of such class anyway and to help it with protected constructor does not make much sense. This is based on information that you provide, author may have reasons but you may misunderstand the concept.

Comment: Please check my post. I think the problem is with nomenclature. "Abstract" in terms of C++ and "abstract" in terms of OO design. In C++ to have pure-virtual method, you must make your class 'virtualized', that is - it must contain a "virtual method" (i.e. that pure one), so it adds a vtable and blahblah.. Hence, to "just make the class abstract" in sense of OO - it is unwieldy. By marking the ctor as protected, you need no virtual methods, and no vtable. Such class is lighter, yet still not instantiable on its own.

Comment: You can use protected constructor yes. That irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the whole point of that suggestion is what-ifs, core-readability and mainterance.

In C++ if you have any pure virtual method in your class, then it is considered *abstract* and automatically non-instantiable. No protected ctors/dtors needed for that. There are some kung-fu ways of creating something like an object-of-an-abstract-class, but if you know how to do that, that's your paradigm problem :)

However, term "abstract" also could be considered just a generic description of the class's purpose. It would be very strange to *require* that every such 'abstract' class simply has to need a pure virtual method. What if it does not make any sense for that class? You'd have to introduce a completely irrelevant p-v-method just to mark the class as 'abstract'.. By marking the ctors as protected you ensure that your-class-without-pure-virtuals is also not freely creatible.

There's also small impact on mainterance: imagine you have an absolutely abstract class with some virtual methods and one pure virtual. You leave ctors/dtors public. Then, after a half-of-a-year you patch/upgrade/modify the class and you change the pure-virtual to be not 'pure', and to have some default implementation. Whoops. Now your class is creatible. [I intentionally ignore the fact that pure virtuals **can have** implementation for the sake of contrived example].

Of course, completely another issue is - what good would be such abstact-base-without-virtual-methods for? I can't find an example of usage except for building a flag-based semi-polymorphism:

```
struct Base { protected: base(){} public: int type; }
struct Derived1:Base { derived1(){type=1;} int shoesize; string codename; }
struct Derived2:Base { derived2(){type=2;} string name, family; }
```

where you could pass derived1/2 by base pointer and detect their type by the 'type' flag, and later manually cast them.. no RTTI, no vtable, very light objects. Sometimes you need it.

Hence, there is some gain in making them protected, but that gain is .. well, small.

Comment: Can you describe the purpose of creating abstract class without any virtual method?

Comment: @Slava, consider a class that follows this article about [virtuality](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm). A class full of template methods, but all virtual ones provide a default implementation. Now, what makes more sense: Choose a method at random and make it "pure virtual", or declare the ctor as protected?

Comment: @Slava - very good question. I was just updating my post with a code sample that makes use of an abstract nonvirtual base. It is nondynamic type recognition without using RTTI. Sometimes vtables are to expensive, or sometimes your platform ... does not support RTTI at all. Remember that C++ is highly multi-paradigm and highly multi-platform too.

Comment: @StoryTeller we can discuss usability of your example separately. But it is irrelevant to the question. Question is why should constructor of abstract class be always protected. But you answer question: why it could be usable to have protected constructor to simulate abstraction sometimes. Do you see the difference?

Comment: I actually -1 your answer as misleading. You can say that such practice can be usable, but you answer to question if it makes sense to enforce such practice.

Comment: @Slava, I always ignore people who recommend to always write code a certain way.

Comment: Notice by your example that you recommend bad practice, as struct Base { virtual int type() const = 0; }; will make that less error prone. Good example to show that you should not do that.

Comment: @Slava: Of course you are free to have a different view, but please read more carefully next time. The question was dual, about "why is recommended" and "how can be misused". I've answered both of them. I have shown what (small) gain you get by following the rule, and also I've described a (corner) case where NOT following the rule opens your code to misuse. If you doubt the latter, please reread the paragraph "There's small impact" down to "Now your class is creatible". Moreover, it is a recomendation, not a requirement. Feel free to ignore it. Personally, I ignore it. Some may like elsewise.